# cakephp multiple find conditions

Tags: cakephp, find, nested, conditional-statements

I want to find with multiple conditions using CakePHP Find All results and matching some more conditions from HABTM table, I want to again search the result with more applied / changed parameters.

So any idea, or a better way suggestions for doing the same?

Will Appreciate your ideas/views.

Thanks !

Comment: Can you be more specific about the models involved and the fields you want to filter against?

Comment: you can find the same question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5567777/cakephp-habtm-join-issue

Comment: if you find my question relevant, please remove your downvote

Comment: also added a new question, with all details: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5591266/cakephp-multiple-join-findall-conditions-issue you can refer to help me out..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

iamtheladylegend,

You would simply set up your findall according to the book. Once your find is returned, you have data in a form, which you can use exactly as a generated `edit()` does. Now you change the search parameters and re-send with the already obtained output as new input.

Comment: thanks for your answer, but it will affect my page load speed i think, when i have hundred of records.. is it so?

Comment: you can download debug_kit and check the timings for your special setup.