# CakePHP multiple JOIN findAll Conditions issue

Tags: cakephp, join, conditional-statements, findall

Here is my `complex (atleast i think it is complex)` condition to find competitors from matches schedules and relating to events.

Now I have `HTBTM` relations with `events_competitors` table, where multiple events have multiple competitors users entries.

Here, I have used `joins` condition for joining and getting related `events` with `competitors` which works fine, but I also want to apply additional conditions, for `is_black` (check for black belt) and `is_adult` (check for adult person)

```
'EventCompetitor.is_black' => 0,
'EventCompetitor.is_adult' => 0,
```

Here I want only those competitors which have both conditions (is_black / is_adult) 0, means not eligible, but it does not applying the same, which is resulting in wrong competitors results.

Below is my whole find condition:

```
$matchdivisions = $this->Competitor->find("all" , 

                               array(

                                'conditions' => 

                                   array(

                   'Competitor.status' => 1, 
                   'Competitor.payment_completed' => 1,
                   'Competitor.weightgroup_id' => $current_matchsc['Matchschedule']['weightgroup_id'],
                   'Competitor.rank_id' => $current_matchsc['Matchschedule']['rank_id'],
                   'Competitor.degree_id' => $current_matchsc['Matchschedule']['degree_id'],
                   'Competitor.gender' => $current_matchsc['Matchschedule']['gender'],

                                    ),

                                    'joins' => 

                                      array(

                                        array(

                                           'table' => 'event_competitors',
                                           'alias' => 'EventCompetitor',
                                           'type' => 'left',
                                           'conditions'=> array(

                                                "AND" =>array(

                        'EventCompetitor.event_id = '.$current_matchsc['Event']['id'],
                        'EventCompetitor.is_black' => 0,
                        'EventCompetitor.is_adult' => 0,

                                                      )
                                                 ),
                                           )
                                     ),

                                    'group' => 'Competitor.id'

                                  )

                             );
```

Any idea, how can i get those things applied into `JOIN` conditions, so it is applied into results.

Thanks !

Below is SQL Dump for your ref:

SELECT `Competitor`.`id`, `Competitor`.`first_name`, `Competitor`.`last_name`, `Competitor`.`parent_name`, `Competitor`.`gender`, `Competitor`.`date_of_birth`, `Competitor`.`email_address`, `Competitor`.`weight`, `Competitor`.`weightgroup_id`, `Competitor`.`height`, `Competitor`.`rank_id`, `Competitor`.`degree_id`, `Competitor`.`photo`, `Competitor`.`school_id`, `Competitor`.`years_of_experience`, `Competitor`.`age`, `Competitor`.`tournament_id`, `Competitor`.`total_registration_fees`, `Competitor`.`address1`, `Competitor`.`address2`, `Competitor`.`city`, `Competitor`.`zip_code`, `Competitor`.`country_id`, `Competitor`.`state_id`, `Competitor`.`phone_number`, `Competitor`.`mobile_number`, `Competitor`.`payment_mode`, `Competitor`.`email_sent`, `Competitor`.`payment_completed`, `Competitor`.`status`, `Competitor`.`created`, `Competitor`.`modified`, `Rank`.`id`, `Rank`.`name`, `Rank`.`status`, `Rank`.`created`, `Rank`.`modified`, `Tournament`.`id`, `Tournament`.`tournament_name`, `Tournament`.`tournament_type`, `Tournament`.`tournament_date`, `Tournament`.`venue_name`, `Tournament`.`address1`, `Tournament`.`address2`, `Tournament`.`city`, `Tournament`.`zip_code`, `Tournament`.`country_id`, `Tournament`.`state_id`, `Tournament`.`created`, `Tournament`.`modified`, `Country`.`id`, `Country`.`name`, `Country`.`status`, `Country`.`created`, `Country`.`modified`, `State`.`id`, `State`.`country_id`, `State`.`name`, `State`.`short_name`, `State`.`status`, `State`.`created`, `State`.`modified`, `Degree`.`id`, `Degree`.`rank_id`, `Degree`.`name`, `Degree`.`status`, `Degree`.`created`, `School`.`id`, `School`.`name`, `School`.`address1`, `School`.`address2`, `School`.`city`, `School`.`zip_code`, `School`.`country_id`, `School`.`state_id`, `School`.`phone_number`, `School`.`owner_name`, `School`.`establishment_date`, `School`.`total_competitors`, `School`.`status`, `School`.`created`, `School`.`modified`, `Transaction`.`id`, `Transaction`.`competitor_id`, `Transaction`.`noncompetitor_id`, `Transaction`.`created`, `Transaction`.`modified`, `Transaction`.`mc_gross`, `Transaction`.`address_status`, `Transaction`.`payer_id`, `Transaction`.`address_street`, `Transaction`.`payment_date`, `Transaction`.`payment_status`, `Transaction`.`address_zip`, `Transaction`.`first_name`, `Transaction`.`address_country_code`, `Transaction`.`address_name`, `Transaction`.`custom`, `Transaction`.`payer_status`, `Transaction`.`address_country`, `Transaction`.`address_city`, `Transaction`.`payer_email`, `Transaction`.`verify_sign`, `Transaction`.`txn_id`, `Transaction`.`payment_type`, `Transaction`.`last_name`, `Transaction`.`address_state`, `Transaction`.`receiver_email`, `Transaction`.`item_name`, `Transaction`.`mc_currency`, `Transaction`.`item_number`, `Transaction`.`residence_country`, `Transaction`.`transaction_subject`, `Transaction`.`payment_gross`, `Transaction`.`shipping`, `Transaction`.`test_ipn`, `Transaction`.`pending_reason` FROM `competitors` AS `Competitor` left JOIN event_competitors AS `EventCompetitor` ON (`EventCompetitor`.`event_id` = 3 AND `EventCompetitor`.`is_black` = 0 AND `EventCompetitor`.`is_adult` = 0) LEFT JOIN `ranks` AS `Rank` ON (`Competitor`.`rank_id` = `Rank`.`id`) LEFT JOIN `tournaments` AS `Tournament` ON (`Competitor`.`tournament_id` = `Tournament`.`id`) LEFT JOIN `countries` AS `Country` ON (`Competitor`.`country_id` = `Country`.`id`) LEFT JOIN `states` AS `State` ON (`Competitor`.`state_id` = `State`.`id`) LEFT JOIN `degrees` AS `Degree` ON (`Competitor`.`degree_id` = `Degree`.`id`) LEFT JOIN `schools` AS `School` ON (`Competitor`.`school_id` = `School`.`id`) LEFT JOIN `transactions` AS `Transaction` ON (`Transaction`.`competitor_id` = `Competitor`.`id`) WHERE `Competitor`.`status` = 1 AND `Competitor`.`payment_completed` = 1 AND `Competitor`.`weightgroup_id` = 13 AND `Competitor`.`rank_id` = 11 AND `Competitor`.`degree_id` = '0' AND `Competitor`.`gender` = 'Female' GROUP BY `Competitor`.`id`

Here is the left join condition from above query for ref:

`left JOIN event_competitors AS EventCompetitor ON (EventCompetitor.event_id = 3 AND EventCompetitor.is_black = 0 AND EventCompetitor.is_adult = 0)`

Comment: please format your code, and also copy an SQL dump from debug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be using the containable behavior for this.  More at: http://book.cakephp.org/view/1323/Containable

1. Add it to your Competitor model.

```
var $actsAs = array('Containable');
```

1. Update your model relationships in your Competitor model to include the is_black and is_adult conditions:

```
    
var $hasAndBelongsToMany = array(
                'Competitor' => array(
                    'className' => 'Competitor',
                    'joinTable' => 'event_competitors',
                    'alias' => 'EventCompetitor',
                    'conditions' => array(
                        'EventCompetitor.is_black' => 0,
                        'EventCompetitor.is_adult' => 0
                    )
                 )
            );
```

3) To inject the event id, pass a contain array to your find operation:

```
$contain = array(
    'EventCompetitor' => array(
        'conditions' => array('EventCompetitor.event_id' =>  $current_matchsc['Event']['id'])
    )
);
$matchdivisions = $this->Competitor->find("all" , 
    array(
        'contain' => $contain,
        'conditions' => array(
            'Competitor.status' => 1, 
             'Competitor.payment_completed' => 1,
            'Competitor.weightgroup_id' => $current_matchsc['Matchschedule']['weightgroup_id'],
            'Competitor.rank_id' => $current_matchsc['Matchschedule']['rank_id'],
            'Competitor.degree_id' => $current_matchsc['Matchschedule']['degree_id'],
            'Competitor.gender' => $current_matchsc['Matchschedule']['gender']
        )
    )
);
```

If is_black and is_adult are not always required for the relationship, you would want to move those conditions from the model and pass them in via the contain parameter of the find operation as needed.

Comment: hi, thanks for your good reply, but i tried the same which doesn't help me in fetching results.. can u exchange your mail id, so i can ask you more about..

Comment: is there any way, i can check whether a containable works with my find query in cake?

Comment: i tried the same, but it doesn't help much, even it's not running the `event_id` join condition after applying containable behavior.